# selecting from the results of a previous select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSql and trying to write a query that involves selecting from the results of a previous select, but cant seem to work the syntax out.

The sub-query part(i.e. lines 2-11) of the following statement

```
WITH getJournalEbmStats AS (
    SELECT
        e.email AS EBM,
        er.status AS reviewStatus,
        count(er.status) AS reviewStatusCount
    FROM
        schemaName.editor_journals ej
        JOIN schemaName.editor e ON e.id = ej.editor_id
        JOIN schemaName.em_user eu ON eu.email = e.email
        JOIN schemaName.em_review_user eru ON eru.user_id = eu.id
        JOIN schemaName.em_review er ON er.id = eru.review_id
    WHERE
        ej."role" = 'someCondition'
        AND ej.stop_date IS NULL
        AND ej.journal_acronym = 'someOtherCondition'
    GROUP BY
        e.email,
        er.status
    ORDER BY
        e.email ASC,
        er.status ASC
)
SELECT
    EBM AS EBM,
    --(select reviewStatusCount from getJournalEbmStats where EBM = getJournalEbmStats.EBM and reviewStatus = 32) as completedReviewCount,
    --(select reviewStatusCount from getJournalEbmStats where EBM = getJournalEbmStats.EBM and reviewStatus = 256) as terminatedReviewCount,
    sum(reviewStatusCount) AS totalReviewCount,
    -- completedReviewCount replaces 100 below
    100 / sum(reviewStatusCount) AS percentCompleteReviews,
    -- terminatedReviewCount replaces 100 below
    100 / sum(reviewStatusCount) AS percentTerminatedReviews
FROM
    getJournalEbmStats
GROUP BY
    EBM
ORDER BY
    percentCompleteReviews DESC
```

generates a data-set that looks like the following.

| EBM | reviewStatus | reviewStatusCount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| email1 | 16 | 88 |
| email1 | 32 | 53 |
| email1 | 128 | 2 |
| email1 | 256 | 1 |
| email1 | 512 | 2 |
| email2 | 8 | 1 |
| email2 | 16 | 20 |
| email2 | 32 | 50 |
| email2 | 128 | 18 |
| email2 | 256 | 3 |
| email3 | 4 | 1 |
| email3 | 8 | 2 |
| email3 | 16 | 11 |
| email3 | 32 | 8 |
| email3 | 512 | 1 |

which I'm then trying to select items from using the additional 2 other (currently commented out) sub-queries to end up with a data-set that looks like

```
email1  [reviewStatusCount when reviewStatus = 32]  [reviewStatusCount when reviewStatus = 256] ...
email2  [reviewStatusCount when reviewStatus = 32]  [reviewStatusCount when reviewStatus = 256] ...
email3  [reviewStatusCount when reviewStatus = 32]  [reviewStatusCount when reviewStatus = 256] ...
```

but can't seem to work out the syntax required to achieve it. If I uncomment the either of the 2 commented out sub-queries then I get the following error message:

```
SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Could anybody put me out of my misery and let me know what the error might be? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    EBM AS EBM,
    sum(reviewStatusCount) AS totalReviewCount,
    sum(reviewStatusCount ) filter where (reviewStatus = 32) AS completedReviewCount,
    sum(reviewStatusCount ) filter where (reviewStatus = 256) AS terminatedReviewCount,
    100 / sum(reviewStatusCount) AS percentCompleteReviews,
    100 / sum(reviewStatusCount) AS percentTerminatedReviews
FROM
    getJournalEbmStats
GROUP BY
    EBM
ORDER BY
    percentCompleteReviews DESC;
```

useful tutorial link: https://modern-sql.com/feature/filter

Comment: Thanks Mark, a useful summary at the link you sent

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who finds they have a similar problem, I eventually discovered the FILTER statement and solved the above using:

```
coalesce(sum(reviewStatusCount) filter (where reviewStatus = 32),0) as completedReviewCount,
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy one but the question is not written well , but all good.

I have a question here , do you want the sum of your score of the count ?

either way it will be the best to do that in your sub query . and just write a one line condition to select your data .

the query will be as follow :

```
sum(reviewStatusCount) filter (where reviewStatusCount = 25)
```

or

```
count(reviewStatusCount) filter (where reviewStatusCount = 25)
```

if you need more description please ask and I will help you